# HTML5 video in IE9 plays when using <video src=""> but not <source src="">

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

If I set my video tag up to be something like

```
<video src="myvid.mp4"></video>
```

IE9 plays the video in its entirety, if however I have it as

```
<video>
    <source src="myvid.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="myvid.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="myvid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

The video plays for about 3 seconds and then stops.

Unfortunately if I use the first method then browsers like Firefox don't look at the `<source>` attributes and refuse to play.

Lots of research has ruled out MIME types and video encoding as potential issues.

The full code for what I currently have is:

```
<video controls="controls" poster="<?=$template_path;?>/images/home-video.png">
    <source src="<?=$template_path;?>/videos/intro_blue.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="<?=$template_path;?>/videos/intro_blue.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="<?=$template_path;?>/videos/intro_blue.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" width="600" height="600">
        <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=<?=$template_path; ?>/images/home-video.png&amp;file=<?=$template_path; ?>/videos/intro_blue.mp4" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <img alt="Intro" src="<?=$template_path; ?>/images/home-video.png" width="600" height="600" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below">
    </object>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it seemed to be IE9 behind certain firewalls was not allowing the video to download completely (other browsers allowed it).

I wasn't happy with this so as a precaution I forced IE9 to use flash.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be in server settings. You don't need the MIME type for video content. And IE is strict with it. [See here for example](http://geekswithblogs.net/Wessty/archive/2011/03/13/ie9-and-the-mystery-of-the-broken-video-tag.aspx).

Comment: All the MIME types are set and correct, I have checked and the debug in IE9 returns that the video is present, and as I say it even starts to play (for about three seconds).